# How to fix Eclipse project upgrade issues?

Tags: force.com-ide, summer-15

I updated the force.com plugin to 35.0 .I am getting below error on trying to upgrade my project to summer 15.

Unsupported_API_Version - Invalid Api version specified on URL.

Any idea how to resolve it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">;
    <apiVersion>32.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

Comment: Please post the exact metadata that is causing your issue.

Comment: It doesn't show any error log.

Comment: Your class should have a file with the `.cls-meta.xml` extension. Post its contents.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>32.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>

Comment: Removed the latest update to IDE and its back to normal now.